# Cannot connect to Parallels VM over network

Tags: macos, networking, parallels

I am trying to connect to my VM (Windows Server 2008 R2) through my Mac.

I have tried

- Host only network,
- Shared network and
- Bridged,

but I cannot connect with any of them. I am just trying to get to port 80. I cannot ping from my Mac to the VM, but I can ping from the VM to the Mac.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More than likely the [Windows Firewall](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545423) is doing its job.  You can create exceptions, or just disable it in Services.

Comment: apparently I cannot mark this as correct yet. I will when I can. Thanks for the quick and correct reply

Comment: Firewall on which side? VM or host?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any antivirus/firewall installed on the VM? Typically McAfee or Nrorton "Security" settings block ping and such network traffic.